# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY' during Testing

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jdbc

Hi I have this test class which saves 3 entity class to database.
**Also the first save stores the cast entity twice.**

```
@Test
//    @Transactional
public void test() throws ParseException {
    //Creating a movie
    Movie movie1 = new Movie();
    movie1.setMovieName("Movie One");
    movie1.setPlot("Sample Plot1");
    movie1.setReleaseDate(new Date(DateUtils.dateToMilliSecondsConverter(20160101L)));
    //Creating cast
    Cast cast1 = new Cast("male", "lead", Type.MALE_LEAD);
    Cast cast2 = new Cast("female", "lead", Type.FEMALE_LEAD);
    List<Cast> cast = new ArrayList<>();
    cast.add(cast1);
    cast.add(cast2);
    //adding cast to movie
    movie1.setCast(cast);
    movie1.setRuntime(120);
    movieDAO.saveOrUpdate(
    //Creating a movie
    Movie movie2 = new Movie();
    movie2.setMovieName("Movie Two");
    movie2.setPlot("Sample Plot2");
    movie2.setReleaseDate(new Date(DateUtils.dateToMilliSecondsConverter(20160101L)));
    movie2.setRuntime(120);
    movieDAO.saveOrUpdate(movie2);
    CinemaHall ch = new CinemaHall();
    ch.setName("Odeon");
    ch.setMovie(new ArrayList<Movie>() {
    {
        add(movie1);
        add(movie2);
    }
    });
    cinemaHallDAO.saveOrUpdate(ch);
```

}

Entity Class are as follows

CinemaHall.java

```
public class CinemaHall{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Movie.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Movie> movie = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Movie.Java

```
public class Movie implements Common {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String movieName;
    private Date releaseDate;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Cast.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Cast> Cast = new ArrayList<>();
    private String plot;
    private Integer runtime;
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class)
    private List<String> showTimings = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Cast.Java

```
public class Cast{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private Type type;
}
```

I get the below error when I run the above mentioned test.

> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not
>   execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:164)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:741)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:589)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:485)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
>     at
>   com.movie.ticketing.dao.MovieDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d00001d8.saveOrUpdate()
>     at com.movie.ticketing.dao.TestApp.test(TestApp.java:52)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:670)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could
>   not execute statement     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2921)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3421)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:560)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:434)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1295)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:468)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3135)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2352)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:581)
>     ... 38 more Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:932)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5094)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
>     ... 56 more

Comment: the test passes with @ Transactional. Shouldn't it pass even without it? without the @ Transactional it gives the above mentioned error

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using?

Comment: 5.1.0.Final @Naros

Comment: Are you cleaning up properly afterwards with something like `@Rollback @After public void tearDown(){}`?

Comment: When I am testing db stuff I always write code to delete and recreate database every time I run the program.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson I have configured Hibernate the same way.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create

Comment: @MickMnemonic `@Transactional` does the `@RollBack` as well. As I said already, if I am using `@Transactional` the test passes; without that I get the above mentioned error.